# Unity game - generate circuit with line drawing

Tags: unity-game-engine, line, generator, mesh, renderer

I'm not a very beginer in unity, but not so far ;). 
Today, I want to make a game which is a mix pool pinball. 
The game physic is quite ok for me, but my big challenge is :
[what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0wBp.jpg)

Allow the player to draw his own circuit and then place the different item : bumper, sticky wall ...

I make it in 3D, but with the camera position, it will be like 2D. 
First of all, I don't know how to make curvy gameobject. I know about bezier curve generator, but not how generate shape with.

Ideally, it would be great if I could : draw a line (with the mouse or finder position) like a line renderer component and then unity extrude in one direction the field circuit. And that' it I have my circuit.
The second challenge will be to place (whit mouse or finger) the different component : bumper, players... with some rules : A sticky wall have to be on a simple wall from the circuit, not in the middle, you have to alway keep some space for the balls etc...
Then we create a game circuit, then we could play :):)

I work with the last unity version.

Obviously, I don't expect a full solution:rolleyes:, but according to you, is it possible ? And which way, which technic I should learn to do that? Which could be the big issu ? ... any remark advice is good to take.

I already begin to look at https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutori...ation-tutorial/creating-meshes?playlist=17153, I d'ont know if it's completly too much or not ?

Many thanks for your help,
Axel

Comment: You can look into linerenderer.bakemesh option. With that you can generate a line by moving the renderer with your mouse/touch. and then at the end of it, bake the line renderer to a mesh.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. 
How do you bake the line renderer component to get a mesh, I don't fin any example of that...

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.BakeMesh.html . Basically in this function you have to pass a game object with empty mesh filter that'll receive the baked mesh and will finally be used as your level. There's also an option for camera for making the linerenderer's line face only in a particular direction as opposed to being always camera facing in every direction. You can achieve a top-down mesh by placing a 2nd camera point straight down, and referencing this camera to the line renderer.

Comment: Ok I see a little bit better how it work.
But I still don't get it, (I don't find code example of it)
It take a mesh in input argument. From where come this mesh ?

Comment: You won't find ready code examples of every function :)

The mesh will be a gameObject in your scene hierarchy itself, and will have a meshFilter component on it. This will be referenced to the script that calls bakeMesh and will be passed to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class scri : MonoBehaviour
{
// For saving the mesh------------------------ 
public KeyCode saveKey = KeyCode.F12;
public string saveName = "SavedMesh";

// Concerning mesher--------------------------
public GameObject mesher; //require

public List<Vector3> vertices;
public  List<int> triangles;

public Vector3 point0;
public Vector3 point1;
public Vector3 point2;
public Vector3 point3;

public int loop;
public float size;

public Mesh meshFilterMesh;
public Mesh meshColliderMesh;

// Sprite work
public Color[] pixels;

public Texture2D newTexture;  
public Texture2D oldTexture;  //require

private Sprite mySprite;
private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

public int pathCount;

public GameObject displayerComponent; //require

public PolygonCollider2D polygonColliderAdded; //require

void Start()
{
    // Mesher
    vertices = new List<Vector3> (); 
    triangles = new List<int> (); 
    meshFilterMesh= mesher.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    meshColliderMesh= mesher.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh;
    size = 10; // lenght of the mesh in Z direction
    loop=0;

    // Sprite
    pixels = oldTexture.GetPixels();
    newTexture =new Texture2D(oldTexture.width,oldTexture.height,TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
    spriteRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    ConvertSpriteAndCreateCollider (pixels);
    BrowseColliderToCreateMesh (polygonColliderAdded);

}

void Update()
{
    // Save if F12 press
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(saveKey)){SaveAsset();}
}

public void ConvertSpriteAndCreateCollider (Color[] pixels) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < pixels.Length ; i++ ) 
    { 
        // delete all black pixel (black is the circuit, white is the walls)
        if ((pixels[i].r==0 && pixels[i].g==0 && pixels[i].b==0 && pixels[i].a==1)) {
            pixels[i] = Color.clear;
        }
    }
    // Set a new texture with this pixel list
    newTexture.SetPixels(pixels);
    newTexture.Apply();

    // Create a sprite from this texture
    mySprite = Sprite.Create(newTexture, new Rect(0, 0, newTexture.width, newTexture.height), new Vector2(10.0f,10.0f), 10.0f, 0, SpriteMeshType.Tight,new Vector4(0,0,0,0),false);

    // Add it to our displayerComponent
    displayerComponent.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=mySprite;

    // Add the polygon collider to our displayer Component and get his path count
    polygonColliderAdded = displayerComponent.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();

}

// Method to browse the collider and launch makemesh
public void BrowseColliderToCreateMesh (PolygonCollider2D polygonColliderAdded){
    //browse all path from collider
    pathCount=polygonColliderAdded.pathCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < pathCount; i++)
    {
        Vector2[] path = polygonColliderAdded.GetPath(i);

        // browse all path point
        for (int j = 1; j < path.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j != (path.Length - 1)) // if we aren't at the last point
            {
            point0 = new Vector3(path[j-1].x ,path[j-1].y ,0);
            point1 = new Vector3(path[j-1].x ,path[j-1].y ,size);
            point2 = new Vector3(path[j].x ,path[j].y ,size);
            point3 = new Vector3(path[j].x ,path[j].y ,0);
                MakeMesh(point0,point1,point2,point3);

            } 
            else if(j == (path.Length - 1))// if we are at the last point, we need to close the loop with the first point
            {
            point0 = new Vector3(path[j-1].x ,path[j-1].y ,0);
            point1 = new Vector3(path[j-1].x ,path[j-1].y ,size);
            point2 = new Vector3(path[j].x ,path[j].y ,size);
            point3 = new Vector3(path[j].x ,path[j].y ,0);
                MakeMesh(point0,point1,point2,point3);
            point0 = new Vector3(path[j].x ,path[j].y ,0);
            point1 = new Vector3(path[j].x ,path[j].y ,size);
            point2 = new Vector3(path[0].x ,path[0].y ,size); // First point
            point3 = new Vector3(path[0].x ,path[0].y ,0); // First point
                MakeMesh(point0,point1,point2,point3);
            }
        }
    }
}


//Method to generate 2 triangles mesh from the 4 points 0 1 2 3 and add it to the collider
public void MakeMesh (Vector3 point0,Vector3 point1,Vector3 point2, Vector3 point3){

    // Vertice add
    vertices.Add(point0);
    vertices.Add(point1);
    vertices.Add(point2);
    vertices.Add(point3);

    //Triangle order
    triangles.Add(0+loop*4);
    triangles.Add(2+loop*4);
    triangles.Add(1+loop*4);
    triangles.Add(0+loop*4);
    triangles.Add(3+loop*4);
    triangles.Add(2+loop*4);
    loop = loop + 1; 

    // create mesh 
    meshFilterMesh.vertices=vertices.ToArray();
    meshFilterMesh.triangles=triangles.ToArray();

    // add this mesh to the MeshCollider
    mesher.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh=meshFilterMesh;
}

// Save if F12 press
public void SaveAsset() 
{
    var mf = mesher.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    if (mf)
    {
        var savePath = "Assets/" + saveName + ".asset";
        Debug.Log("Saved Mesh to:" + savePath);
        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(mf.mesh, savePath);
    }
}

}
```

[image]